# Let $C_i=\{i\cdot q^j \pmod{q^m-1}\, ||\, j=0,1,\cdots ,m-1\}$. If $\gcd(i,q^m-1)=1$, then $|C_i|=n$.

Tags: finite-fields

Let
$$
C_i=\{i\cdot q^j \pmod{q^m-1}\, ||\, j=0,1,\cdots ,m-1\}.
$$
*My question:* How to show that if $\gcd(i,q^m-1)=1$, then the cardinality of $C_i$, denoted with $|C_i|$, is equal to $m$.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Since $C_i$ has at most $m$ distinct elements, we only need to show that for $\gcd (i,q^m-1)=1$, $i\cdot q^i \not \equiv i \cdot q^j \pmod {q^m-1}$ for $0\le i \ne j\le m-1$.

Comment: @player3236 Your comment is right. But your comment results in $q^{i-j}=1 \pmod{q^m-1}$ that dose not related to the condition $\gcd(i,q^m-1)=1$.

Comment: No it does not lead to $q^{i-j}=1$. Not if $\gcd(i, q^m-1) >1$. (Also I made a mistake, I shouldn't use $i$ twice.)

Comment: @player3236 Is it possible to request you to help me with more details. Thank you.

Comment: Take $i = 4, q = 3, m = 2$. Then $C_i = 1$ since $4\cdot 3^0 \equiv 4 \cdot 3^1 \pmod 8$, but obviously $3^0 \not \equiv 3^1 \pmod 8$.

Comment: @player3236 In youe example $\gcd(4,3^2-1)\neq 1$. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. I was using this for a counterexample to $i \cdot q^i \equiv i\cdot q^j \implies q^{i-j}\equiv 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll just flush out the proof.

Suppose $0\le j<k \le m-1$.

If $\gcd (i,q^m-1)=1$: $$i\cdot q^j \equiv i \cdot q^k \pmod {q^m-1} \implies q^j \equiv q^k \pmod {q^m-1}$$

Since $\gcd (q^j,q^m-1)=1$: $$q^j \equiv q^k \pmod {q^m-1} \implies 1 \equiv q^{k-j}\pmod {q^m-1}$$

This implies $(q^m-1) \mid (q^{k-j}-1)$.

Together with $k-j\ne0$, this implies $q^{k-j}-1 > q^m-1 > q^k - 1\ge q^{k-j}-1$, which is a  contradiction.

Hence $i \cdot q^j$ are all distinct for $j = 0,1,\dots, m-1$.